# Django serializer.save() gives back a HTTP 500 error response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following straightforward setup: a folder `order` with a `models.py` file,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from product.models import Product

class Order(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
  stripe_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at',]

  def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name

class OrderItem(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

  def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.id
```

a `serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Order, OrderItem

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = OrderItem
    fields = [
      "price",
      "product",
      "quantity",
    ]

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = [
      "id",
      "first_name",
      "last_name",
      "email",
      "address",
      "zipcode",
      "place",
      "phone",
      "stripe_token",
      "items",
    ]

  def create(self, validated_data):
    items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for item_data in items_data:
      OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **item_data)

    return order
```

and finally, a `views.py` file

```
import stripe

from django.conf import settings # get secret key
from rest_framework import status, authentication, permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import OrderSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def checkout(request):

  serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)

  if serializer.is_valid():
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    paid_amount = sum(item.get('quantity') * item.get('product').price for item in serializer.validated_data['items'])

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount=int(paid_amount * 100),
    currency='USD',
    description='Charge from Djackets',
    source=serializer.validated_data['stripe_token']
    )

    serializer.save(user=request.user, paid_amount=paid_amount) 
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

  return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now trying to post to `checkout` gives the 500 response with the following error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table order_order has no column named paid_amount

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\djackets_django\order\views.py", line 35, in checkout      
    serializer.save(user=request.user, paid_amount=paid_amount)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\djackets_django\order\serializers.py", line 37, in create  
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1621, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Larry\django-vue-tutorial\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table order_order has no column named paid_amount[27/Jul/2022 12:34:17] "POST /api/v1/checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 206511
```

This code originates from a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg5zkd9nm6w) that does not explain a whole lot of what is going on. My question is: How to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the error trace? It can be a validation error

Comment: If the problem is with the __serializer.save()__ that means that this method raises an Exception. Could you print it and past the content of it? Also are you sure that this 400 is not caused by the serializer __not__ being valid?

Comment: The following is the 'stack trace' from the console in the browser. Well, if I have the chronological order right, it is just the first view lines (it is very long). Stack Trace: dispatchXhrRequest
xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter
xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest
dispatchRequest.js:58
request
Axios.js:109
httpMethod
Axios.js:144
wrap
bind.js:9
stripeTokenHandler
Checkout.vue:224
submitForm/<
Checkout.vue:192, If this is the wrong trace please let me know.

Comment: Remove try except block Let it crash and then analyze error trace.

Comment: @TymoteuszLao no it is valid.

Comment: I understand that my initial question was really uninformative since I was catching the error myself. I hope the current information is more insightful (I am still learning).

Comment: It looks like a table in your database does not contain a paid_amount column. Can you run the following commands: __python manage.py makemigrations__ and __python manage.py migrate__ and then try again?

Comment: Yea, I run these commands every time I make a change to the models. So now it will just say 'No changes detected' and 'No migrations to apply.' respectively. It is weird because the model 'Order' in models.py does have a column 'paid_amount'.

Comment: Have you manually added entries in http://localhost:8000/admin? If there are no entries in the database, then this "checkout" function when run will give this OperationalError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as stated in the comments running:
`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` did not resolve my problem. It simple gives back that there are no migrations.

I did solve the problem by, similar to switching the on/off button, commenting out the `paid_amount` column on my model and doing the proper migrations. Then, I uncommented the `paid_amount` column did the migrations and then it suddenly worked. I did not change anything to the code so I have no idea why he gave back an error in the first place.

Thanks to all who tried to help, kind of feel bad since in the end a single on/off switch (to the order table) did the trick. But as I said, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you don't have `paid_amount` column in the `order_order` table. If you changed the DB model definition, you need to make a migration and apply it first.

`python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`